# Java: can I know which class was passed?

Tags: java, oop

I have an interface

```
Interface I {}
```

I have 2 classes implementing I.

```
Class A implements I {}

Class B implements I {}
```

Now, I have a new class which takes the interface as member.

```
Class C {
I i; 
}
```

While building this class's object I am passing class A.

```
C c = new C (A a);
```

In a method I want to ensure if I have class A here and not class B.

```
public void test(C c) {
  if (c.getI().getClass().isInstance(A.Class)) {
    return true;
}

}
```

However I am not getting the correct output here.
What I want to know is whether I implemented class A or B in the object of C.
How can I achieve that?

Comment: why do you do a "getClass()" before doing an instanceof check? also: what 'Class' class are you using, and what instanceOf method are you calling? Honestly, I'm surprised this compiles to begin with.

Comment: is that really Java? The standard  `Class` class does not have a `instanceOf()` method, but `isInstance()`,  and the *usual way* to do that would be `c instanceof A` (or, in that specific case, `c.i instanceof A`)

Comment: @user85421 my guess is he created his own Class class some way.

Comment: I just corrected my if condition.

Comment: @Stultuske I have some trouble believing that... how did they make `getClass()` return this *own*  `Class` ? Is that even possible without messing up with bytecode or the JVM?

Comment: @user85421 I doubt all the code is shown, if the code originally posted compiled

Comment: @Stultuske does not matter, `getClass()` is `final`, how you get it to return a different `Class` . . . at least not trivial to just override `getClass` (hard to believe if we consider the *level* of the question ... `Interface` ? `Class` ?)

Comment: (ignoring the other problems like `return true` for `void`; (or no return value at all, if the method was declared to return `boolean`); `if (...)  return true`; `new C (A a)`; ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to see if the `C` class is an instance of `A` and not the field `i` inside of it.

Try with a public `i`: `c.i instanceof A`

Or better with a getter: `c.getI() instanceof A`

Comment: given the code we are shown, how is this supposed to compile?

Comment: my bad, I corrected it. I am trying `c.getI().getClass().instanceOf(A)` actually

Comment: what I want to know is, is it possible that I will get isInstanceOf(A) to be true, if I originally have `I` as the member of class C.

Comment: @user4202236 yes, but that makes no sense at all. you would get compile time errors.

Comment: I think what I need is `c.getI() instanceOf A`. Thanks everyone.

Comment: BTW if you really need reflection: `A.class.isInstance(c.getI())` (I believe)

Comment: @user4202236 you definitely do NOT need instanceOf since that doesn't exist, and thus won't compile

Comment: @Stultuske you are right, i fixed my mistake

Comment: BTW be aware that `instanceof`  does not guarantee that the first *operand* is the **same** class as given by the second *operand* - it can be a subclass of it